# Unhandled Exception: Connection refused during connect signalR in flutter

Tags: asp.net, flutter, signalr, chat

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused during connect signalR in flutter

I want to pass the message one android emulator from another android emulator

this is my flutter code

```
// main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:signalr_netcore/hub_connection.dart';
import 'package:signalr_netcore/hub_connection_builder.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late HubConnection hubConnection;
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  String msg = "No messages yet";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initSignalR();
  }

  void initSignalR() async {
    hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("http://127.0.0.1:5231/signalrHub")
        .build();
    hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", _handleMessage);
    try {
      hubConnection.start();
      print("SignalR connected successfully!");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error connecting to SignalR: $e");
    }
  }

  _handleMessage(List<Object?>? args) {
    if (args != null && args.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        msg = args[0].toString();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("SignalR Flutter Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(hubConnection.state == HubConnectionState.Connected
                ? "signalr is conected"
                : "siganlr is disconnected"),
            Text(msg),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Type a message'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: hubConnection.state == HubConnectionState.Connected
                  ? () {
                      String message = _controller.text;
                      hubConnection.invoke("SendMessage", args: [message]);
                      _controller.clear();
                    }
                  : null,
              child: Text("Send Message"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    hubConnection.stop();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

this is my Asp.net web code

```
using FlutterBackendSignalR.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
   
}

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapHub<ModelViewHub>("/signalrHub");

app.Run();

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace FlutterBackendSignalR.Hubs
{
    public class ModelViewHub:Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to pass the message one android emulator from another android emulator with help of Asp.net signalR